# VBA: How to delete a column based on the adjacent cell containing certain characters?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code to search a series of column headers for any string that contains "_STD" (there are multiple of these, and not always in the same spot on the worksheets). If that substring exists, I want to delete the entire column BEFORE it (OR replace the values in the adjacent column with the "_STD" column values), and then remove "_STD" from the header.

Not sure the code for "contains", but I thought I could do something like:

```
If cell.Value = "_STD" Then cell.EntireColumn.delete(xlToRight)
```

Data example included in the link below:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Use `Range.Find`. Or loop from left to right, checking the header values with `InStr` or `Like` and then deleting as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Like` and `Offset`

```
If cell.Value Like "*_STD" Then 
    cell.Offset(0,-1).EntireColumn.delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `LIKE` but if `_STD` can be case insensitive for example `_Std, _std` etc then I recommend using `INSTR` with `vbTextCompare` as a parameter
2. Here is one way to do it. Delete All columns which *DO NOT* have `_STD` and then bulk replace `_STD` in the header in the relevant row.

For example

```
'~~> You can reverse loop and delete columns which DO NOT have _STD
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "_STD", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
```

And use this code to bulk replace. I am assuming that the headers are in row 1. Change as applicable.

```
.Rows(1).Replace What:="_STD", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```